# After counting occurrences, how to make entries for each day in list

Tags: python, list, date, for-loop, count

I have two columns of dates in two separate csv files. I am reading them into python, and plan to plot in matplotlib

One is for invoices:

```
5/1/2015
5/1/2015
5/1/2015
5/2/2015
5/2/2015
5/2/2015
5/2/2015
5/3/2015
5/3/2015
5/3/2015
5/3/2015
5/4/2015
5/4/2015
5/4/2015
5/4/2015
5/4/2015
5/4/2015
5/5/2015
5/5/2015
5/5/2015
5/5/2015
5/7/2015
```

And the other is for disputes:

```
5/1/2015
5/1/2015
5/2/2015
5/2/2015
5/3/2015
5/5/2015
5/5/2015
```

I want to make a list with the number of disputes divided by the number of invoices per day. So for May 1, 2015 the percent is 2/3. For May 2, 2015 2/4. May 3, 2015 is 1/4. May 4, 2015 is 0. May 5, 2015 is 2/4. There are no invoices or disputes on May 6, 2015 so the percent should be zero. Thus the list should be [.66, .5, .25, 0, .5, 0, 0]

Then I am going to graph the percents on the y axis and the date as the x-axis.

I have tried to use df.index.day but then I get groups for the first day of each month, the second, etc. I was using value_counts to count up the occurrences of each date and then dividing between two lists but I was missing numbers where I didn't have invoices or disputes, and I want there to be a value for every day.

Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to get the counts is to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('invoice_dates') as f:
    invoice_count = Counter(line.strip() for line in f)
```

and similarly for `dispute_count`.  You can then get a dictionary mapping dates to dispute percentages by

```
from __future__ import division # in case you are on Python 2.x
dispute_percentage = {date: dispute_count.get(date, 0) / invoices
                      for date, invoices in invoice_count.items()}
```

Use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` in the last line if you are on Python 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks very pythonic, exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately it seems as though my data set is too large. I am getting this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack. Do you know of a way to avoid this?

Comment: @jenryb: "ValueError: too many values to unpack" is usually caused by something like `var1, var2 = "value1", "value2", "value3"`. It has nothing to do with your data set being too large, but with you trying to put too many values into too few variables (3 into 2 in this example).

Comment: Nevermind! It looks like this is an issue with the `for` on the last line of his code. replace `invoice_count` with `invoice_count.items()`.

Comment: @JakeGriffin that addition fixed it. However, the output has all of the percents being 0.0, which isn't right.

Comment: Could you post your code so that we can see what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: @JakeGriffin Absolutely! I posted the code, input, and output. hope that helps!

Comment: It is not matching up now because your dates are in different formats (mm/dd/yyyy vs yyyy-mm-dd). You will have to make sure the keys in the `dispute_count` and `invoice_count` dicts are the same format or when you do `dispute_count.get(date, 0)`, it is always going to return the default `0`. If you need help with this, I would recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have made it more clear that you were using `pandas`-- there are built-in tools to aid you to do what you want to do.  In this case, you can use `value_counts` on your `f` and `f2`.  With your example data:

```
>>> f = pd.to_datetime(f)
>>> f2 = pd.to_datetime(f2)
>>> f.value_counts()/f2.value_counts()
2015-05-01    0.666667
2015-05-02    0.500000
2015-05-03    0.250000
2015-05-04         NaN
2015-05-05    0.500000
2015-05-07         NaN
dtype: float64
>>> (f.value_counts()/f2.value_counts()).fillna(0.0)
2015-05-01    0.666667
2015-05-02    0.500000
2015-05-03    0.250000
2015-05-04    0.000000
2015-05-05    0.500000
2015-05-07    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This also helps in that my date formats were actually different. Sorry I didn't make it more clear that I was using pandas!